# Trying to replace part of a string which may need Regex pattern matcher?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3,C#, Razor.

I am creating some XHTML from some data.

I need to remove some inline font-size tags that get added accidently, but can cause chaos with the formatting.

So I might have:

```
<p> <span style="font-size: 12px">my text</span> </p>
```

I would like to replace or remove these "font-size" inline CSS rules. I am suspecting that I may need some regex match approach, but am unsure how to go about it, apart from the fact it will be something like:

```
string pattern = <regex pattern for "<style=" and "font-size" CSS attribute>;
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, pattern, "");
```

My intended output is either:

```
<p> <span style="">my text</span> </p>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: for this cases I would to recommend the http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ to parse correctly the html

Comment: Why do you think you need `RegEx`? Does the pixel size change? Are there other attributes wish to keep? If it is always the same `span` tag within `p` tags then you could do a simple string operations.

Comment: Don't you think this can be achieved using replace function of string only ? What you have to do is to check for sub-string in your string and then use replace function of string. that's it..!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The extra <span style="font-size:12px"/> type tags will all be valid. Validity is not the issue here. The fact that it is surplus is the issue. The pixel size could change, therefore I need a way replace the pattern  - <span style="{any spaces}font-size:{any pixel size};color:red"> - to be replaced with <span style="color:red"> i.e remove the font-size name@value attribute.